# Textarea with CKEditor not saving html tags on server side

Tags: mysql, laravel, server, ckeditor, local

I am using Laravel 8, MySQL, and CKEditor. I would like to ask what could possibly be causing a difference between my local and server.

On my local what I enter into the text editor will be saved to the DB along with the html tags.

[image: sample input local]

While on the server, it will only save the text without the html tags

[image: sample input server]

Below is my controller

```
public function store(Request $reqst){
        $new_info = new Information;

        $rules = array(
            'title' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'content' => "required",
        );

        $this->validate($reqst, $rules);

        $new_info->title = $reqst->title;
        $new_info->content = $reqst->content;
        $new_info->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $new_info->save();

        return redirect('/admin/informations');
}
```

Here is my blade

```
<form action="{{ route('informations/add-new-information/store') }}" method="POST" class="col-lg-12 mt-4">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" required placeholder="Maximum of 255 Characters">
                @error('title')
                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @enderror
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="content">Content: <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add New Information</button>
            </div>
        </form>

<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/23.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#content' ) )
        .catch( error => {
            console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

I am trying to figure out why are the html tags not present on server side.

Thanks :)

*** UPDATE! ***

After doing php artisan config:cache, route:cache, and view:cache

The HTML tags are no longer being passed even on local.

Comment: What do you get if, at the start of your store() method, you echo $reqst->content; then die; - does the HTML make it through at that point?

Comment: @GilesBennett I tried this and placed it on the server. No, it doesn't make it through.

Comment: OK, so at least you know that it's not anything in your database or your controller that's doing the naughty bit.

Comment: @GilesBennett Yes, that, at the very least, we can confirm is not the cause of the problem. Thanks

Comment: I cannot replicate this (on local) using your blade content, controller, and a simple model with title / content. The HTML tags make it through the form submission, and are saved into the database with no issue.

Comment: Erm - what PHP version are you running?

Comment: Local is 8.0.12, Server is 7.4 @GilesBennett

Answer (score 0):

you should add this script After the ckeditor.js script

```js
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Amir, Unfortunately, it did not work for me.

Comment: if you use ckeditor version 4. its will work.

Comment: Even using ckeditor 4, it still does not work

Comment: please just add this code after close body tag and remove another ckeditor code:
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.17.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('content');
</script>

Comment: That is what I did.

Comment: can you giva us an image from your console. and your blade html?